# how to compare date string in Perl

Tags: perl

I have two  Perl string  variables containing date values.  I want to check whether str1 variable date value is 1 day before the str2 value.  How can i check it?  if it doesn't have 1 day before str2 then i need to print an error message.

```
 $str1="20120704"
 $str2="20120705
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard Time::Piece module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%Y%m%d';

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($str1, $str2) = split;

  my $dt1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, $format);
  my $dt2 = Time::Piece->strptime($str2, $format);

  print "$str1 / $str2: ";
  if ($dt2->julian_day - $dt1->julian_day == 1) {
    say "ok";
  } else {
    say "not ok";
  }
}

__END__
20120704 20120705
20120630 20120701
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I dont know much about julian_day. Is it safe to use the julian_day? will it create problems at the end of leap year? what does use 5.010 means? Is it requied?

Comment: For our purposes you can consider Julian Day as a number (currently just under 2,500,000) which increases by one every day. It's exactly what you need for this problem. `use 5.010` means "you need at least Perl 5.10.0 to run this program (because it uses `say`). I hope you're not using anything older than that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I have the below time perl modules installed currently in my system. Is there anything i can reuse instead of installing any new perl module Time::piece.  Have the below modules currently - Time/JulianDay.pm Time/ParseDate.pm Time/CTime.pm Time/Timezone.pm Time/DaysInMonth.pm

Comment: There's a reason why I described it as "the standard Time::Piece module". Time::Piece has been included as part of the standard Perl distribution since Perl 5.10.0 which was released over four years ago. If you're using a version of Perl that doesn't include it then you should really consider upgrading. Alternatively, it seems that Time::JulianDay could be used to to this - albeit in a slightly more complex manner. Try reading the documentation (`perldoc Time::JulianDay`).

Comment: Using perl 5.8. Will try to download the time piece module and try it out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
use Date::Parse;
$str1="20120704";
$str2="20120705";
@lt1 = localtime(str2time($str1)); 
@lt2 = localtime(str2time($str2));
if ($lt1[7] + 1 != $lt2[7]) {
  die "$str2 < $str1";
}
```

Comment: `do{$str = '2'.$_.'10'; print $str if eval($str) or print 'no '; print "\n";}for(qw(< > <= >= == !=));` just change value of `$str` for date ;)

Comment: The task was about checking whether the date is *one day* before, not just before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. when i compile i get the error not able to fine parse.pm. From where should i download the perl module

Comment: @Arav: from CPAN. But may be it is already in your OS distributive. Then you just need to install it using `apt-get`/`yum`.

Answer (score 1):

Since those date stamps are in ISO 8601 form, a simple string comparison is sufficient to compare them.

```
if( $str1 gt $str2 ) {
   # $str2 represents a later date than $str1
}
```

This is a specific feature of ISO 8601 form and doesn't necessarily apply to datestamps in other formats. Specifically note that it requires fields in the order year/month/day, and that month and day fields have 0-padding.

Comment: While does compare the dates, it doesn't answer the post, because that was "is 1 day before" not simply "before".